# How can I do full justify alignment

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, richtextbox

I am displaying the text in pages layout, such as Microsoft Word, That every page is a new RichTextBox. and the text alignment is justify (with SETPARAFORMAT message).
But when there is a paragraph that begins on the first page (first RichTextBox) and ends on the second page, the last line of the first page is not justify, how can I do that also last line will be justified?

Comment: Okay, I got it. What about the answer

Comment: @user1543998 [This](http://geekswithblogs.net/pvidler/archive/2003/10/15/182.aspx) may help

Comment: this is standard justify, and it has no effect on the last row. I am looking for full justify.